# Error in Express js/Node js enpoint login isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have a simple CRUD app that make the user register and login
in general.js there's a register endpoint and this's working fine and the login prints

`"message": "Invalid Login. Check username and password"`

```
- index.js
- router
- - general.js
- - auth_users.js
- - booksdb.js
```

[register on postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rthcu.png)

While I got to login endpoint in `auth_users.js`

This's the code of the login of `auth_users.js` which has the login endpoint mainly this's the express function which responsible for the login `regd_users.post()`

```
const express = require('express');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
let books = require("./booksdb.js");
const regd_users = express.Router();

let users = [];

const isValid = (username)=>{ //returns boolean
//write code to check is the username is valid
let userswithsamename = users.filter((user)=>{
    return user.username === username
  });
  if(userswithsamename.length > 0){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

const authenticatedUser = (username,password)=>{ //returns boolean
//write code to check if username and password match the one we have in records.
let validusers = users.filter((user)=>{
    return (users.username === username &&users.password === password)
  });
  if(validusers.length > 0){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
 
//only registered users can login
regd_users.post("/login", (req,res) => {

    const username = req.query.username;
    const password = req.query.password;
    if (!username || !password) {
        return res.status(404).json({message: "Error logging in"});
    }
    if (authenticatedUser(username,password)) {
      let accessToken = jwt.sign({
        data: password
      }, 'access', { expiresIn: 60 * 60 });
      req.session.authorization = {
        accessToken,username
    }
    return res.status(200).send("User successfully logged in");
    } else {
      return res.status(208).json({message: "Invalid Login. Check username and password"});
}
});

// Add a book review
regd_users.put("/auth/review/:isbn", (req, res) => {
  //Write your code here
  return res.status(300).json({message: "Yet to be implemented"});
});

module.exports.authenticated = regd_users;
module.exports.isValid = isValid;
module.exports.users = users;
```

Comment: Please check your grammar, especially the use of periods.  It is hard to understand, for example, whether the following is good or bad: "this's working fine and the login prints ... Invalid Login. Check username and password."  I understand English may be difficult for ESL speakers, but clarity is required for any sort of help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please change your logic to **not** pass credentials via the query string, this is an absolutely critical security issue. Pass them in the request body and read them via `req.body`

Comment: As for this immediate problem, you have a **typo**. You need to compare `user.username` and `user.password` in the filter callback, not `users`

Answer (score -1):

Based on the provided code, there seem to be a issue that might be causing the "Invalid Login" message.

Comparing username and password in authenticatedUser function:
In the authenticatedUser function, you are filtering the users array to find a matching username and password. However, there's an issue with the filter function. Instead of using users.username and users.password, it should be user.username and user.password. The variable should be singular as it represents each element in the users array during iteration.

Change this line:

```
return (users.username === username && users.password === password)
```

to:

```
return (user.username === username && user.password === password)
```